# Ruby: No Block Given error

Tags: ruby

I keep getting a 'no block given' error when trying to pass the string to the is_tut? method.  I am new to Ruby and have no idea what I'm doing wrong.  Any and all help would be appreciated.

```
class Tut
@@consonants = ["b","c","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","m","n","p","q","r","s","t","v","w","x","y","z"]

  def is_tut? string
    if string =~ /^(([b-df-hj-np-z]ut)|([aeiou\s])|[[:punct:]])+$/i
      yield
    else
      false
    end
  end

  def self.to_tut string 
        string.each_char do |c|
            c += "ut" if @@consonants.find { |i| i == c.downcase }
            yield c
        end
    end

    def self.to_english string
        array = string.split //
        array.each do |c|
            if @@consonants.find { |i| i == c.downcase }
                array.shift
                array.shift
            end
            yield c
        end
    end


end

#Tut.to_tut( "Wow! Look at this get converted to Tut!" ) { |c| print c }
# should output : Wutowut! Lutookut atut tuthutisut gutetut cutonutvuteruttutedut tuto Tututut!

puts
puts

tut = Tut.to_tut( "Wow! Look at this get converted to Tut!" )
puts "from return: #{tut}"

puts

#Tut.to_tut( "Wutowut! Lutookut atut tuthutisut gutetut cutonutvuteruttutedut tuto Tututut!" ) { |c| print c }
# should outout : Wutowut! Lutookut atut tuthutisut gutetut cutonutvuteruttutedut tuto Tututut!
puts
puts

#tut = Tut.to_tut( "Wutowut! Lutookut atut tuthutisut gutetut cutonutvuteruttutedut tuto Tututut!" )
#puts "from return: #{tut}"

puts

#tut_string = ""
#Tut.to_tut( "I'm in tut but I want to be in english." ) { |c| tut_string += c }
#puts tut_string
# should output : I'mut inut tututut bututut I wutanuttut tuto bute inut enutgutlutisuthut.

puts

#Tut.to_english( tut_string ) { |c| print c }
# should output : I'm in tut but I want to be in english.
```

Comment: Just as a tip, a more Ruby-ish way to define your consonants would be: `@@consonants = ('a' .. 'z').to_a - %w[a e i o u]`

Comment: In Ruby, indentation is normally two spaces.

Comment: It looks right in Textmate, think it just didn't paste correctly.

Answer (score 20):

If you have `yield` within your method definition, that means you have to obligatorily pass a block when you use it (unless the part including it is not executed according to conditioning etc.). (You might already know, but in case you don't: a block is something that is described as `{...}` or `do ... end`) And `yield` will refer to the block.

If you want to make a block optional, then one way to do it is to put the `&` symbol before the variable name.

```
def method(argument, &block_argument)
   if block_argument # block is given
      block_argument.call(argument_for_block) # use call to execute the block
   else # the value of block_argument becomes nil if you didn't give a block
      # block was not given
   end
end
```

This will allow optional block. Or, as suggested by Squeegy,

```
def method(argument)
   if block_given? # block is given
      yield(argument_for_block) # no need to use call to execute the block
   else 
      # block was not given
   end
end
```

will also work.

Comment: Or you could just use `block_given?` to something like `yield if block_given?`

Comment: That's another good way. `block_given` checks if there is a block, and if not, it returns false, and `yield` will not be executed, which means it will not cause an error.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're calling `yield` in your `to_tut()` method, this line will fail:

```
tut = Tut.to_tut( "Wow! Look at this get converted to Tut!" )
```

You either *need* to give a block (as you did in the first commented-out call to `Tut.to_tut()`), *or* you need to modify your `to_tut()` function to [make the code block optional](http://blog.codahale.com/2005/11/24/a-ruby-howto-writing-a-method-that-uses-code-blocks/):

```
def self.to_tut string 
    string.each_char do |c|
        c += "ut" if @@consonants.find { |i| i == c.downcase }
        yield c if block_given?
    end
end
```

Comment: Sweet!!  That worked!  Thanks everyone!  I may be back here with more questions later.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

`yield` requires a block to be passed to `to_tut`.

When you do:

```
Tut.to_tut( "Wow! Look at this get converted to Tut!" ) { |c| print c }
```

It works because it has the block `{ |c| print c }`.

Without a block it will raise the error.